# Commission base payment gateway

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I want to implement the commission base payment gatway in one of my project(iOS,Android and Javascript).

Commission base product means : 
1)User A send the amount to Website owner through payment getway.

2)Website owner deduct their commission for providing some service.

3)Website will transfer the rest amount(Through API or by some method) to UserB

I had check  :- 1)https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-payments-overview/
2)https://www.ccavenue.com/payment_gateway.jsp

But it is not mention any where.
Please advice how to implement the commission base payment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need from paypal is something called "Adaptive payments", specifically "chained payment". Using their API will you be able to do exactly what you have described about commission base payment.

Please find more information here:
[Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)